# Letsencrypt for two Node API applications on separate ports on the same DigitalOcean Droplet instance?

Tags: linux, ssl, lets-encrypt, digital-ocean

I have two Node applications running on a DigitalOcean Droplet.  These are personal side projects for learning, so some best-practices are being intentionally ignored for this exercise.  The goal, is to get SLL certs acquired and auto-renewing for both.  So I have:

- ApplicationFoo running on both ports 80 and 443 (static and API service)
- ApplicationBar running on port 8080 (just an API)

I am certain that I have my DNS settings set up correctly for both of these applications, `www.foo.com` and `api.bar.com` both point to the IP address of this Droplet.

I found a tutorial on the DigitalOcean website:
[here it is](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-let-s-encrypt-certificates-for-multiple-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04)

But it doesn't work.  When I run the following command:

```
letsencrypt certonly --webroot -w /home/bar/api/public -d api.bar.com
```

I get the following awful response:

```
Domain: api.bar.com
Type:   unauthorized
Detail: Invalid response from
https://foo.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/some_crazy_hash
[correct.ip.address]: 404
```

Well of course it won't work if `foo.com` is responding to requests for cert authorization for `bar.com`!  How can I get this all to play nicely together so I can have these services both running on a single Droplet?

Motivation: prevent doubling my cost to run extra Droplets for learning/experimenting projects.

Comment: How have you configured your web server? What is it?

Comment: Yes, everything is working.  I figured it out moments after posting this question.  You can register the cert for the domain pointing to the secondary server using the static service of the first.  I was trying to figure out how to force letsencrypt to send the cert for the second server/domain to the second server over the second server's port, which is pointless.